# Do Kafka Streams replay source topics if state store didn't get flushed into changelog?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

**Question about State Stores and Rebalancing**
**Let say :**

- We have 2 input topics and we are aggregating records and pushing into a table.
- We have offset 10 of Topic 1 and offset 100 of Topic 2 are successfully aggregated
- Problem: Offset 11-13 of Topic 1 and offset 101-102 of topic 2 aggregation happened in-memory but didn’t make in changelog topic of state store.
- Question: In changelog topic it has its own offset and new consumer will have state up to that. Will it have any link that Offset 11-13 and offset 101-102 has to be replayed? Because these offsets might have been committed if I understand correctly?

Please guide any material specific to this OR if you know the answer it will be much appreciated. TIA

I am aggregating and thinking if used cache (RocksDb) how it will work if something failed as highlighted above.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question ², the changelog is source of truth for your state stores so in your case , you will have a data loss if your changelog is behind your local state store.

Comment: That is where my question is. Will Kafka replay the offsets from source topics somehow?

Comment: On application restart, the Streams API “detects” these changelog topics and any existing local state  data, and it ensures that the internal state is fully built up and ready before the actual processing starts based on the last committed offset

Comment: Microservices world there is no local state. As it will be brand new container spinned up.

Comment: That's only if you use stateless operations, which by the description you provided won't be possible. You'll have to offer a way to keep state in the microservice, such as using Statfulset with PVC on K8s.

Comment: That makes sense actually. If state is saved as shared volumn between pods then they don't need to rebuild all.

Comment: Not sure to understand your point but if you talk about aggregation then you have states , by definition . One more thing , sharing the same data space is a bad practice in my opinion . Even more with Kafka stream . Your instances must be  highly decoupled and let Kafka manage your states from the data stored in the broker , not from your shared space